# What is the difference between Terminal and Root Terminal?

Tags: command-line, root, katoolin

It is a totally different app that I have installed using Katoolin. The app looks similar to Terminal, and maybe it does the same tasks.

What is it and how is it different from Terminal?

I tried to use it but whenever I click on the icon it asks me for a password, but my password isn't correct, so I cannot use it.

[image]

Comment: A root terminal is a terminal running a shell process as the root user and therefore with ultimate privileges. This requires your account password to unlock, and of course your account must be allowed to elevate privileges. I don't know what your application uses internally (`sudo`, `pkexec`, ...) to elevate privileges, but that automatic privilege elevation should be the whole difference to a "normal" terminal.

Answer (score 2):

The default Kali user is `root` and the Root Terminal application that was installed by the Katoolin script provides the same functionality in Ubuntu, however it should be mentioned that the single user, root access policy of Kali Linux is not recommended for Ubuntu users. In Kali Linux the default user is `root` and the default root password is `toor`. Using the default root password is a security risk, so either the Root Terminal application should be uninstalled or else **the default root password should be replaced by a strong password**.

From [Kali Linux Root User Policy](http://docs.kali.org/policy/kali-linux-root-user-policy)

> Most Linux distributions, quite sensibly, encourage the use of a
>   non-privileged account while running the system and use a utility like
>   sudo when and if escalation of privileges in needed. This is sound
>   security advice: this provides an extra layer of protection between
>   the user and any potentially disruptive or destructive operating
>   system commands or operations. This is especially true for multiple
>   user systems, where user privilege separation is a requirement —
>   misbehavior by one user can disrupt or destroy the work of many users.
>
> Kali Linux, however, as a security and auditing platform, contains
>   many which tools can only run with root privileges. Further, Kali
>   Linux’s nature makes its use in a multi-user environment highly
>   unlikely.
>
> For these reasons, the default Kali user is "root", and no
>   non-privileged user is created as a part of the installation process.
>   This is one reason that [Kali Linux is not recommended for use by Linux
>   beginners](http://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux) who might be more apt to make destructive mistakes while
>   running with root privileges.